# Adding methods when subclassing `Struct`

Tags: ruby, methods, struct, scope

The [documentation of `Struct::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Struct.html#method-c-new) has the following snippet:

```
Customer = Struct.new('Customer', :name, :address) do |new_class|
  p "The new subclass is #{new_class}"
  def greeting
    "Hello #{name} at #{address}"
  end
end           # => Struct::Customer
dave = Customer.new('Dave', '123 Main')
dave # =>     #<struct Struct::Customer name="Dave", address="123 Main">
dave.greeting # => "Hello Dave at 123 Main"
```

Why does `greeting` become a method of the created subclass? It's passed to the block as an argument. Apparently, it also becomes the context in which the block is executed. Similarly:

```
[1,2,5].each { |x|
  public
  def m1 a
    a + self
  end
}[0].m1 3
```

gives 4. But unlike with `Struct`, the method is private by default. Strange.

Comment: "*But unlike with Struct, the method is private by default.*" How do you conclude the method is private?

Comment: @ByteEater: The behaviour in your case is defined [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Struct.html#method-c-new): _With a block given, the created subclass is yielded to the block_

Comment: @Schwern, without `public` I get:
```
(file): eval:1:in `<main>': private method `m1' called for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: @user1934428, I don't think so. That sentence means the block gets the subclass as argument. The same way the block after `each` gets the elements iterated over.

Comment: @ByteEater I see now. I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: I guess the documentation forgets to say, that `self` in the block is also bound to that subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does greeting become a method of the created subclass?

The short answer is: because that's how `Struct.new` works.

Why would it work that way? Imagine if it didn't. `greeting` would be added to all Structs and that would be bad.

> It's passed to the block as an argument.

This is the "how". The "block" is really you defining a function and passing it into `new`. The code above is syntax sugar for...

```
func = Proc.new do |new_class|
  p "The new subclass is #{new_class}"
  def greeting
    "Hello #{name} at #{address}"
  end
end

Customer = Struct.new('Customer', :name, :address, &func)
```

See [The Ultimate Guide to Blocks, Procs & Lambdas](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/#Understanding_Ruby_Blocks) for more.

`Struct.new` runs the proc, passing in the name of the new class, but it runs it in a special way. It runs it as if it were the class `Struct::Customer`. It does this (probably) by calling [`class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_exec) to run a proc as if it were defined inside another class.

We can do the same to demonstrate.

```
class Foo
  # Defined inside the Foo class, farewell is a method of Foo.
  def farewell
    "goodbye"
  end
end

# This proc is defined outside the Foo class...
func = Proc.new do
  def greeting
    "hello"
  end
end

# ...but we can run it as if it were.
Foo.class_exec(&func)

dave = Foo.new
p dave.greeting
```

Many Ruby libraries use this trick, and ones like it.

---

The block passed to `each` is also a proc, but `each` just runs it normally passing in each element of the Enumerable.

However, what you're written is rather odd. This...

```
[1,2,5].each { |x|
  public
  def m1 a
    a + self
  end
}[0].m1 3
```

Is really this.

```
nums = [1,2,5].each { |x|
  public
  def m1(a)
    a + self
  end
}

nums[0].m1(3)
```

Which is really this.

```
[1,2,5].each { |x|
  public
  def m1(a)
    a + self
  end
}

1.m1(3)
```

`each` returns what it iterated over, so it returns `[1,2,5]`. `nums[0]` is 1. So we're calling `m1` on an Integer. Why would `m1` be defined on an Integer?

It isn't! It's actually defined on `Object`. Why?

Everything is an object in Ruby, there always has to be a `self`. When outside a class in Ruby, `self` is `main` which is an `Object`. `m1` is a method of `Object`.

```
p self         # main
p self.class   # Object
```

`Integer` inherits from `Object` so it can call `m1`. We can see this using [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-method). Everything is an object, including [Method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html)s.

```
p self.method(:m1)  #<Method: Object#m1>
p 1.method(:m1)     #<Method: Integer(Object)#m1>
```

That says m1 is defined on Object and Integer inherits it from Object.

But why is it private? Any method defined like this is defined on `Object`. (Almost) everything inherits from `Object`. If it were public, methods in a script would be polluting other classes. So they're private. This is a special case only for main.

---

Defining `m1` in `each` is a red herring. `each` is just running the code but doing nothing special. You can just define it in `main` (ie. Object) and get the same effect.

```
public
def m1(a)
  p a + self
end

p self.method(:m1)
p 1.method(:m1)
```

Comment: @ByteEater I expanded the answer to explain what's going on with `each`.

Answer (score 1):

Run this program and it will print out the answer to your question:

```rb
puts "A: self is #{self} so methods defined here get added to #{self}"

Customer = Struct.new('Customer', :name, :address) do |new_class|
  puts "B: self is #{self} so methods defined here get added to #{self}"
end

[1].each do |x|
  puts "C: self is #{self} so methods defined here get added to #{self}"
end
```

Also, in your example, note that `greeting` is not passed to the block as an argument.  In fact what is going on is that the block contains code that defines the `greeting` method, and before the block runs, that method does not exist.

The [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/struct.c) of `Struct.new` is written in C so it's kind of hard to tell what it does exactly, but it probably does something like `self_changer` in the code below in order to execute the given block with a different `self`:

```rb
def self_changer(&proc)
  some_object = "abcd"
  some_object.instance_eval(&proc)
end

self_changer do
  puts "self is #{self}"
end
```

Comment: Indeed, "`greeting` is not passed to the block as an argument". I meant the pronoun to refer to the created subclass. Sorry if I worded it unclearly, I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Very nice set of examples, @david-grayson, elucidating! But why does it happen? What in the language semantics is leveraged by `Struct::new` to make `self` the created subclass inside the block, as opposed to `each`?

Comment: I added another scrap of code at the bottom of my answer to explain how it's possible to execute a block with a different `self`.